# Overwriting or updating string inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was given a simple task of writing a code to uppercase the odd indexed charachters of a string inside a list , to which i coded as follows :

```
list1 = []
x = int(input("Enter the size of list : "))
for i in range(x):
    temp = str(input("Enter the element you wish to insert : "))
    list1.append(temp)
for i in range(x):
    size = len(list1[i])
    for j in range(size):
        if j%2 == 0:
           list1[i][j].replace(list1[i][j],list1[i][j].upper())
print(list1)
```

but it doesn't seems to be working and on printing the list1 it simply returns the normal string inside list . Help a beginner out

Comment: `.replace` does not work in-place, `str` objects are immutable

Comment: Which, in beginner, means: `.replace()` doesn't modify the variable passed to it, instead it returns the result of the replacement. You can assign the result to a variable to achieve what you want e.g. `myString = myString.replace(a, b)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need the inner for loop. You can just check if `i` divided by 2 is equal to 1 and replace it.

```
list1 = []
x = int(input("Enter the size of list : "))
for i in range(x):
    temp = str(input("Enter the element you wish to insert : "))
    list1.append(temp)
for i in range(x):
    if i%2==1:
        list1[i]=list1[i].upper()

print(list1)
```

Example:

```
Enter the size of list : 4
Enter the element you wish to insert : a
Enter the element you wish to insert : b
Enter the element you wish to insert : c
Enter the element you wish to insert : d
['a', 'B', 'c', 'D']
```

---

If you want to change case of individual characters of elements, you can do the following:

```
list1 = []
x = int(input("Enter the size of list : "))
for i in range(x):
    temp = str(input("Enter the element you wish to insert : "))
    list1.append(temp)

for i in range(x):
    list1[i]=''.join(i.upper() if j%2==0 else i for j,i in enumerate(list1[i]))
print(list1)
```

Output:

```
Enter the size of list : 3
Enter the element you wish to insert : cat  
Enter the element you wish to insert : hen 
Enter the element you wish to insert : pig
['CaT', 'HeN', 'PiG']
```

Comment: my intended result is not : 

Enter the size of list : 4
Enter the element you wish to insert : a
Enter the element you wish to insert : b
Enter the element you wish to insert : c
Enter the element you wish to insert : d
['a', 'B', 'c', 'D']

but this

Enter the size of list : 4
Enter the element you wish to insert : dog
Enter the element you wish to insert : cat
Enter the element you wish to insert : hen
Enter the element you wish to insert : rat
['DoG', 'CaT', 'HeN', 'RaT']

Comment: @Parth Please wait for a minute

Answer (score 2):

Why not try `enumerate` with list comprehension:

```
list1 = []
x = int(input("Enter the size of list : "))
for i in range(x):
    temp = str(input("Enter the element you wish to insert : "))
    list1.append(temp)
list1 = [''.join(x.upper() if not (idx % 2) else x for idx, x in enumerate(i)) for i in list1]
print(list1)
```

Example output:

```
Enter the size of list : 4
Enter the element you wish to insert : dog
Enter the element you wish to insert : cat
Enter the element you wish to insert : hen
Enter the element you wish to insert : rat
['DoG', 'CaT', 'HeN', 'RaT']
```

Comment: I was just about to edit my answer with ```enumerate```

Comment: @Sujay Haha! That surely is a pretty handy function :)

Comment: my intended result is not : 

Enter the size of list : 4
Enter the element you wish to insert : a
Enter the element you wish to insert : b
Enter the element you wish to insert : c
Enter the element you wish to insert : d
['a', 'B', 'c', 'D']

but this

Enter the size of list : 4
Enter the element you wish to insert : dog
Enter the element you wish to insert : cat
Enter the element you wish to insert : hen
Enter the element you wish to insert : rat
['DoG', 'CaT', 'HeN', 'RaT']

Comment: @Parth Does it work?? please check my answer

Comment: You don't need to create a list to join the strings

Comment: @Sujay For longer lists performance-wisely brackets would be faster but for this little example it's not needed, thanks for the suggestion, edited my answer :)

Comment: @Parth May you please upvote my answer as well?

Answer (score 1):

I would improve the second loop by doing a stepped [range](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp#:%7E:text=stop%20(not%20included).-,step,Optional.%20An%20integer%20number%20specifying%20the%20incrementation.%20Default%20is%201,-More%20Examples) and the problem with your code is that you don't overwrite the new string in the list. The replace function only returns the string with the replaced character, does not replace it in the original list.

I did an example using string slicing which might be simpler to understand.

```
for i in range(x):
    if len(list1[i]) == 0:
        continue
    for j in range(1, len(list1[i]), 2):
        list1[i] = list1[i][:j] + list1[i][j].capitalize() + list1[i][j+1:]
```